# Private social share API

Tags: library, api, social-networks, web-apis, sharing

Is there any private social share API?

Requirements are:

- Available as PHP or JavaScript library
- Well supported
- Shares on Facebook, Twitter, Google Plus, Pinterest

What's NOT needed:

- Heavy-weight scripts which clutter DOM
- Any intermediate websites involved
- Support for over 9000 services

Basically, it should just combine native APIs and reflect any changes in them quickly.

As I experienced AddThis, ShareThis, Shareaholic all require too much JavaScript, include many unwanted things in DOM and do all sharing via their servers.

Comment: Found http://sharrre.com/ and I am pretty happy with it! It supports sharing on Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Pinterest, LinkedIn, Delicious, Digg, StumbleUpon. Well commented and the JS file weights only 14kb. Also, was updated just 10 days ago. Think, I'll stick with this one for now.

Comment: It would be great if you could add this as an answer, highlighting how it matches your requirements and describing your experiences with it so far.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the best option I found is [sharrre.com](http://sharrre.com/).

---

It supports sharing on:

- Facebook,
- Twitter,
- Google Plus,
- Pinterest,
- LinkedIn,
- Delicious,
- Digg,
- StumbleUpon.

---

Here is HTML to create a Tweet button:

```
<div id="twitter"></div>
```

You can pass data attributes and script will pick them up for you:

```
<div id="twitter" data-text="Yummy!" data-url="http://pinterest.com/deegong/steak/"></div>
```

For me it's very straightforward and convenient way, as I can generate data attributes dynamically on server and pass them to Javascript very easy.

---

The javascript *(depends on jQuery)* looks as follows:

```
$('#twitter').sharrre({
    share: {
        twitter: true
    },
    template: 'Tweet [{total}]',
    enableHover: false,
    enableTracking: true,
    buttons: { 
        twitter: {
            via: 'ruchevits'
        }
    },
    click: function(api, options){
        api.simulateClick();
        api.openPopup('twitter');
    }
});
```

Options are well documented here: http://sharrre.com/#documentation

---

The script will bind an *onClick* to `#twitter` container and place the following inside:

```
Tweet [0]
```

That was actually the expected behaviour, when I tried things myself without even reading documentation. Really pleased that there's no any weird output.

Here is what you get `onClick` in a popup, resized to fit content:

[image: Twitter share popup]

---

The script is just about **14kb** (minified `addthis_widget.js` is roughly **7kb**, but it doesn't include any sharing calls itself).

And finally, it is updated regularly (last update - 10 days ago), so you can check Github for any updated third-party URLs.

I sincerely recommend this plugin to anyone who likes "transparent" lightweight code.

Personal **THANK YOU!** to [Julienh on Github](https://github.com/Julienh) for the great job!

---

**EDIT:**

Took me about 30 minutes to make these metro buttons fully working. :)

[image: Metro buttons]